# Running Excel macro in a specific workbook fails from C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I'm trying to run a macro in an Excel workbook from C# using the standard Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library. In my scenario the version of Excel could be either 2010 or 2013.

There could be multiple workbooks open for the same Application object, each potentially with the same macro names, so I'm explicitly passing in the workbook name

```
string macro = string.Format("{0}!{1}", workbook.Name, macroName);
Application.Run(macro);
```

Weirdly, I get a COMException if the workbook name has hyphens in it:

```
Application.Run("My-Workbook!macro1")
```

But runs fine without hyphens:

```
Application.Run("MyWorkbook!macro1")
```

Is it just me or is this weird? Can anyone think of a workaround?

Comment: have you tried to [wrap the hypen workbook in single quotes](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?16786-Bug-in-Run-Application-Excel-2003-dash-in-filename)

Comment: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm  Always safer to quote the workbook name...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the workbook name in [quotes](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?16786-Bug-in-Run-Application-Excel-2003-dash-in-filename)

```
string macro = string.Format("'{0}'!{1}", workbook.Name, macroName);
Application.Run(macro);
```